# MySQL LEFT Join displaying incorrect data

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join

I have got 5 tables of which the structures are the same.  Only the `PAGEVISITS` field is unique

ie. table 1:

```
ITEM |   PAGEVISITS   |  Commodity
1813       50            Griddle
1851       10            Griddle
11875      100           Refrigerator
2255       25            Refrigerator
```

ie. table 2:

```
ITEM |   PAGEVISITS   |  Commodity
1813       0             Griddle
1851       10            Griddle
11875      25            Refrigerator
2255       10            Refrigerator
```

I want it to add up the `Commodity` to spit out:

```
table1   |   table2   |  Commodity
60           10          Griddle
125          35          Refrigerator
```

Some of the data is actually correct but some are WAY off given the below query:

```
SELECT
SUM(MT.PAGEVISITS) as table1,
SUM(CT1.PAGEVISITS) as table2,
SUM(CT2.PAGEVISITS) as table3,
SUM(CT3.PAGEVISITS) as table4,
SUM(CT4.PAGEVISITS) as table5,
(COUNT(DISTINCT MT.ITEM)) + (COUNT(DISTINCT CT1.ITEM)) + (COUNT(DISTINCT CT2.ITEM)) + (COUNT(DISTINCT CT3.ITEM)) + (COUNT(DISTINCT CT4.ITEM)) as Total,
MT.Commodity
    FROM table1 as MT
       LEFT JOIN table2 CT1
       on MT.ITEM = CT1.ITEM
       LEFT JOIN table3 CT2
       on MT.ITEM = CT2.ITEM
       LEFT JOIN table4 CT3
       on MT.ITEM = CT3.ITEM
       LEFT JOIN table5 CT4
       on MT.ITEM = CT4.ITEM
GROUP BY Commodity
```

I believe this may be cause by using the `LEFT JOIN` incorrectly.  I have also tried the `INNER JOIN` with the same inconsistent results.

Comment: You should use a `full outer join` which isn't available in MySQL. Try using `left outer join` and `right outer join` and combine it with `union`.

Comment: what result do you currently obtain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do a UNION on all five of those tables to get them as one rowset (inline view), and then run a query on that, start with something like this...

```
SELECT SUM(IF(t.source='MT',t.pagevisits,0)) AS table1
     , SUM(IF(t.source='CT1',t.pagevisits,0)) AS table2
     , t.commodity
  FROM ( SELECT 'MT' as source, table1.* FROM table1 
          UNION ALL  
         SELECT 'CT1', table2.* FROM table2
          UNION ALL
         SELECT 'CT2', table3.* FROM table3
          UNION ALL
         SELECT 'CT3', table4.* FROM table4
          UNION ALL
         SELECT 'CT4', table5.* FROM table5
      ) t
GROUP BY t.commodity
```

(But I would specify the column list for each of those tables, rather than using the '.*' and having my query dependent on no one adding/dropping/renaming/reordering columns in any of those tables.)

I include an "extra" literal value (aliased as "source") to identify which table the row came from. I can use a conditional test in an expression in the SELECT list, to figure out whether the row came from a particular table.

This approach is particularly flexible, and can be used to get more complicated resultsets. For example, if I also wanted to get a total number page visits from table3, 4 and 5 added together, along with the individual counts.

```
SUM(IF(t.source IN ('CT2','CT3','CT4'),t.pagevisits,0) AS total_345
```

---

To get the equivalent of your `COUNT(DISTINCT item) + COUNT(DISTINCT item) + ...` expression...

I would use an expression that makes a single value from both the "source" and "item" columns, being careful to have some sort of guarantee that any particular "source"+"item" will not create a duplicate of some other "source"+"item".  (If we just concatenate strings, for example, we don't have any way to distinguish between 'A'+'11' and 'A1'+'1'.)  The most common approach I see here is a carefully chosen delimiter which is guaranteed not to appear in either value.  We can distinguish between 'A::11' and 'A1::1', so something like this will work:

```
 COUNT(DISINCT CONCAT(t.source,'::',t.item))
```

In your current query, if `item` is NULL, then the row doesn't get included in the COUNT. To fully replicate that behavior, you would need something like this:

```
 COUNT(DISINCT IF(t.item IS NOT NULL,CONCAT(t.source,'::',t.item),NULL)) AS Total
```

Or course, getting a count of distinct item values over the whole set of five tables is much simpler (but then, it does return a different result)

```
 COUNT(DISINCT t.item)
```

---

But to answer your question about the use of the `LEFT JOIN`, the left side table is the "driver" so a matching row has to be in that table for a corresponding row to be retrieved from a table on the right. That is, unmatched rows from the tables on the right side will not be returned.

If what you have is basically five "partitions", and you want to process all of the rows whether or not a matching row appears in any of the other "partitions", I would go with the `UNION ALL` approach to simply concatenate all of the rows from all of those tables together, and process the rows as if they were from a single table.

NOTE: For very large tables, this may not be a feasible approach, since MySQL is going to have to materialize that inline view. There are other approaches which don't require concatenating all of the rows together.

Specifying a list of only the columns you need, in the SELECT from each table, may help performance, if there are columns in those tables you don't need to reference in your query.

---